# How to find the OSM tag information along the route obtained using Mapbox direction API

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am building a navigation app using the Mapbox Direction API.

I want to obtain the OSM tag information along the route.
The tag information like speed limits, stop signs, traffic signals, number of lanes, one way, etc

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a backend, you can use OSM's [Atlas](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas) tool:

- Download an osm pbf file for the location you are looking at, for example from [geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/).
- Load the pbf into an Atlas object: https://github.com/osmlab/atlas#building-an-atlas-from-an-osmpbf-file Make sure to use a bounding box to save up memory.
- Use the Atlas APIs to access the data: https://github.com/osmlab/atlas#using-atlas

Example: From a latitude/longitude use [Location](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas/blob/bb6102043640d96a64229010d984cacc8c95c60b/src/main/java/org/openstreetmap/atlas/geography/Location.java) and then query using a small bounding box:

```
long osmIdentifier;
Location location;
atlas.edgesIntersecting(location.bounds().expand(Distance.ONE_METER))
        .forEach(edge -> 
            {
                if (edge.getOsmIdentifier() == osmIdentifier)
                {
                    System.out.println(edge.getTags());
                }
            });
```